# Android studio error in putting listener in notification function using if else

Tags: java, android, notifications

I tried to put PendingIntent Notification in my android project but i had this error it says *wrong first argument found android view.View.OnClickListener required android content,context.*

Am going to show the code error , the "this" under else notification has its error.

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
```

this error

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int targetId = view.getId();


        if (targetId == R.id.button) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have " + numMessages++ + " message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            if (numMessages > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setTicker("You Have " + numMessages++ + " message")
                        .setContentTitle("OneDiver")
                        .setContentText("Content")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_od_icon_24dp)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, noti);


            }
        }
```

Comment: write like `YourActivityName.this` instead of `this`

Comment: do you have preferences regarding on how to put a notification inside a app , like popping up on a icon , like in facebook. i've searched for this references but non of the result answer my question, on how to put notification on a app. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is in an activity, say YourActivity.class, you need to replace "this" with "YourActivity.this". Because in an OnClickListener, "this" is referring to the OnClickListener instead of the activity.

Comment: do you have preferences regarding on how to put a notification inside a app , like popping up on a icon , like in facebook. i've searched for this references but non of the result answer my question, on how to put notification on a app. thanks!